# how select2 work correctly in table after add new row?

Tags: javascript, html

when i add a new row in table. select2 remain selected items and disabled items inside select2 in a new row. 
so, i do not want to remain selected items when added new row and select2 work without disabled itself

I tried put switch case for select but not work for select2

```js
 $(document).ready(
    function () {

        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();


    }

)
            
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount > -1);
  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
      var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
      newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[2].cells[i].innerHTML;
      switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
      case "text":
          newcellchildNodes[0].value = "";
          break;
      case "checkbox":
          newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
          break;
      case "select-one":
          newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
          break;
      }

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md mg-t-20 mg-md-t-0">
<div class="card ">
<div class="card-body">
<h4 class="card-title tx-dark tx-medium mg-b-10"></h4>
<div class="ht-40 bd bg-primary pd-x-20 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
<h3 class="tx-white mg-t-5"></h3>
<div class="mg-l-auto">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-light bd-0 ht-35 " type="button"
title="Add New" onclick="addRow('datatablergncon');  ">
                                        <span>
<h5 class="tx-white fa fa-plus"> ADD NEW ROW</h5>
</span></button>
</div>
</div><!-- ht-65 -->

<div class="table-wrapper">
<div id="datatable1_wrapper" class="datatables_wrapper no-footer"
style=" height:300px;overflow:auto;">
<table id="datatablergncon" class="table display responsive nowrap dataTable no-footer dtr-inline " role="grid" aria-describedby="datatable1_info">
<thead>
<tr role="row">
<th class="wd-15p " tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable1" rowspan="1"
colspan="1" style="width: 112px;" aria-sort="ascending">
Name
</th>
<th class="wd-15p " tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable1" rowspan="1"
colspan="1" style="width: 112px;" aria-sort="ascending">
select
</th>
<th class="wd-15p" tabindex="0" aria-controls="datatable1" rowspan="1"
colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending">
option
</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr role="row" class="odd" >
<td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1" >
<INPUT type="text" name="txt" class="form-control" />
</td>
<td >
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple col-md-4" name="states[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%">
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="bo">boooiiiuu</option>
<option value="ca">cat</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs " type="button" value="Delete"                                               onclick="deleteRow('datatablergncon', this)" title="Delete Row"><span class="icon ion-trash-a"></span> Delete</button> 
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- card -->
</div>
<!--col-->
</div><!-- row -->
```

select2 not work correctly

Answer (score 0):

from official document: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items, you need to do it like this

```
$('#mySelect2').val(null).trigger('change');
```

Comment: it is clear old and new row . and new row appears disabled

Comment: You can select which one to clear by yourself. Use select2 official method to manipulate DOM object, don't editing html directly, it will not have correct event handling.

Comment: maybe this :) https://pawelgrzybek.com/cloning-dom-nodes-and-handling-attached-events/